# I'm having problems with MVN

Tags: javascript, maven

hi so i'm new and I cloned a repo from github and i need to run mvn clean install to proceed, but I get an error and not sure how to solve it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe5Wo.png)

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, and they even give you a link to documentation to help solve it.

Comment: A project without a `pom.xml` file is not a maven project. If you have one then execute the command in the same directory as the `pom.xml`. Also, please don't use images to provide required info in questions but add them in the form of text

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in general.

Comment: You're using Maven with JavaScript code?